# Transforming Numbers to Time in Excel

Tags: excel

I have been given a spreadsheet in Excel where the time is input as 715,810, 935, etc which is supposed to represent 7:15am, 8:10am, 9:35am, etc. My question is if there an easy way to transform these numbers so that they actually represent the time values they are supposed to?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `TIME` function.
Dividing the number as an integer by 100, gives you the hours.
The integer remainder contains the minutes.

```
=TIME(INT(A1/100),INT(MOD(A1,100)),0)
```

Comment: Yeah, sure. The input is numbers. :D

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this number of yours in A1 cell. Then the formula is:

`=TIME(VALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)),VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2)),0)`